# How do I fix these errors? I just wanted to connect my project to Firebase and I am getting all these errors

Tags: android

```
[Fatal Error] core-common-2.1.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] collection-1.1.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog. 
[Fatal Error] viewpager-1.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog. 
[Fatal Error] core-1.1.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.     
[Fatal Error] activity-1.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog. 
[Fatal Error] lifecycle-viewmodel-2.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] loader-1.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.   
[Fatal Error] core-common-2.1.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] collection-1.1.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] loader-1.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] activity-1.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog. 
[Fatal Error] core-1.1.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] viewpager-1.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] lifecycle-viewmodel-2.0.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

I just tried to run the simple Flutter app when a new project is created, and I keep getting these errors. Can anyone please try and help me fix this cos I am new to flutter and Dart